# neuralnet package producing a single result

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm using the neuralnet package to try and predict a sample of some continuous data, but for some reason it only produces one predicted value, which interestingly enough is not the mean.

Is there any common known cause for this? I've tried wildly/randomly varying the values of threshold, the number of nodes and the learningrate to no avail, as the predictions are still a constant.

Here's some output from the learning process

```
hidden: 40    thresh: 0.3    rep:  1/10    steps:     762   error: 0.39832  time: 5.65 secs
hidden: 40    thresh: 0.3    rep:  2/10    steps:      18   error: 0.33205  time: 0.21 secs
hidden: 40    thresh: 0.3    rep:  3/10    steps:      22   error: 0.33204  time: 0.18 secs
hidden: 40    thresh: 0.3    rep:  4/10    steps:      22   error: 0.33203  time: 0.19 secs
hidden: 40    thresh: 0.3    rep:  5/10    steps:      14   error: 0.33206  time: 0.11 secs
hidden: 40    thresh: 0.3    rep:  6/10    steps:      16   error: 0.33206  time: 0.14 secs
hidden: 40    thresh: 0.3    rep:  7/10    steps:      19   error: 0.33204  time: 0.14 secs
hidden: 40    thresh: 0.3    rep:  8/10    steps:      22   error: 0.33207  time: 0.19 secs
hidden: 40    thresh: 0.3    rep:  9/10    steps:    1000   min thresh: 1.054522176
                                                     1300   error: 0.3486   time: 11.05 secs
hidden: 40    thresh: 0.3    rep: 10/10    steps:      23   error: 0.33206  time: 0.22 secs
```

Has anyone experienced or fixed a similar problem?

Comment: you probably need to post a reproducible example <http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000>

Comment: @BenBolker probably meant this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example